# R -- Finding non-complex solution from function "polyroot"() with "Im()"

Tags: r, complex-numbers

I am having trouble finding the non-complex solution from the complex array provided by **polyroot()**.

```
coef1 = c(-10000,157.07963267949,0,0.523598775598299)
roots=polyroot(coef1)
```

returns

```
##[1]  23.01673- 0.00000i -11.50837+26.40696i -11.50837-26.40696i
```

and I would like the index that doesn't have an imaginary part.  In this case:

```
roots[1]
## [1] 23.01673-0i
```

I am going to apply this process in a loop and would like to use **Im()** to isolate the non-complex solution, however, when I try using:

```
Im(roots)
## [1] -2.316106e-23  2.640696e+01 -2.640696e+01
```

and therefore cannot use something like:

```
which(Im(roots)==0)
```

which returns

```
##integer(0)
```

I am confident there is a real root given the plot from:

```
plot(function(x) -10000 + 157.07963267949*x + 0.523598775598299*x^3,xlim=c(0,50))
abline(0,0,col='red')
```

Is there some funny rounding going on?  I would prefer a solution that doesn't involve **ceiling()** or anything similar.  Any of you R experts have any ideas?  Cheers, guys and gals!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a certain error or threshold:

```
Re(roots)[abs(Im(roots)) < 1e-6]
[1] 23.01673
```

Graphically :

[image]

```
curve(-10000 + 157.07963267949*x + 0.523598775598299*x^3,xlim=c(0,50))
abline(0,0,col='red') 
real_root <- Re(roots)[abs(Im(roots)) < 1e-6]
text(real_root,1,label=round(real_root,2),adj=c(1,-1),col='blue')
```

Comment: I recommend scaling the tolerance value against the mean, or minimum, of the real parts of the roots.  I agree that anything below 1e-16 is almost certainly machine-precision-limited error.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the absurdly small imaginary part of the first root.  It's a rounding issue, which are unfortunately common when computers do floating-point operations.  Though it's a little inelegant, try

```
which(round(Im(roots), 12)
```

which will round it to 12 decimal places (more precision than you probably need).

Comment: check out the `zapsmall` function